# Copy() function not working properly. PHP

Tags: php, copy, mkdir

I've been trying and trying, but I can't seem to get this to work. I saw a similar solution on this website, but it just doesn't work for me.

I'm trying to pass a default profile picture into the user's folder. The folder is created for the user, but it remains empty.

Any suggestions/ideas?

PHP:

```
$profile_pic = $row['avatar'];  
        //$g = gender   
        if($g == "f"){
                $profile_pic = "default_woman.jpg";
            } else{
                $profile_pic = "default_man.jpg";
            }
            '<img src="img/'.$profile_pic.'" >';
// Add user info into the database table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, username, email, password, gender, country, avatar, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck)       
                VALUES('$fn','$ln','$u','$e','$p_hash','$g','$c','$profile_pic','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
        $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql); 
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db);
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
        if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
            mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
        }
        copy($profile_pic,"user/$u/$profile_pic");
```

Comment: It looks like the directory is not writable. 0766 would be the right octal to set the permissions to depending on 'who' your PHP scripts run as.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Not shown in the question, I have `mysqli_real_escape_string` and `preg_replace` called out for the posted data. I'm currently looking into prepared statements, as I think they'll be a better option (so I've heard). @JayBlanchard

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion about the 0766, I tried it as well as 0777, and still nothing is in the folder. @JayBlanchard

Comment: 0766 is dangerous, because anybody can write to the directory. 0755 is perfectly fine, because the same user (web server) creates the directory and the profile image in it. Maybe there's a permission problem with /user, though.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not safe. *Always* use prepared statements.

Comment: PHP gives you errors and warnings and notices - if you'd look at them you'd see that the source might not be found (without any relative path it seems to be in the current directory - but which is the current one?). Also remove code parts that aren't related to your problem (i.e. DB access).